# Case classes inheriting from abstract class

Tags: class, scala, inheritance, case

I'm currently learning Scala and I have some problems designing my case classes. I need two case classes that have the same properties. So I thought I would be a good idea to inherit from an abstract base class that defines these properties. However this code does not compile

```
abstract class Resource(val uri : String)

case class File(uri : String) extends Resource(uri)
case class Folder(uri : String) extends Resource(uri)
```

because `uri` in the case class constructors would overwrite the `uri` property of the base class.

What would be the correct way to design this?

I want to be able to do something like this

```
val arr = Array[Resource](File("test"), Folder("test2"))

arr.foreach { r : Resource => r match {
  case f : File => println("It's a file")
  case f : Folder => println("It's a folder")
} }
```

The "equivalent" Java code should be something like

```
abstract class Resource {
   private String uri;

   public Resource(String uri) {
       this.uri = uri
   }

   public String getUri() {
       return uri;
   }
}

// same for Folder
class File extends Resource {
    public File(String uri) {
        super(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
abstract class Resource {
   val uri: String
}

case class File(uri : String) extends Resource
case class Folder(uri : String) extends Resource


Stream[Resource](File("test"), Folder("test2")) foreach { 
  r : Resource => r match {
   case f : File => println("It's a file")
   case f : Folder => println("It's a folder")
} }
```

---

**EDIT**

Without case classes:

```
abstract class Resource(val uri : String)

class File(uri : String) extends Resource(uri) {
   override def toString = "..."
}
object File {
   def apply(uri: String) = new File(uri)
}

class Folder(uri : String) extends Resource(uri) {
   override def toString = "..."
}
object Folder {
   def apply(uri: String) = new Folder(uri)
}
```

Comment: However this duplicates the `uri` property and getter in both `File` and `Folder`. Is there any chance to get clean code that looks like the Java example in my question?

Comment: Then why you use case classes? Case classes add getter and setters. Write normal classes and their companion objects.

Comment: Because this would be too much boiler plate code? ;-) Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Thanks! And I don't need an `unapply()` because `case f : File =>` matches on the class of the object?

Comment: yes, you need unapply if you want to write something like: r match { case File(b) => ... }

Answer (score 5):

Make these two case class extends a common trait which define it interface and it should work.

BTW, you need an identifier before the type clause in `case` statement.

```
trait Resource {
    val uri: String
}

case class File(uri : String) extends Resource
case class Folder(uri : String) extends Resource

val arr = Array[Resource](File("test"), Folder("test2"))

arr.foreach { r : Resource => r match {
  case s: File => println("It's a file")
  case s: Folder => println("It's a folder")
}}
```

Comment: This works however the uri property and getter methods are stored in both `File` and `Folder`(duplicate). I was hoping to have some clean code like the Java example above (I've updated my question).